# Rewrite subfolder to index.php file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite the url `http://www.host.com/de/rss` to the file `http://www.host.com/index.php?type=9000001&L=1`

My rewrite rule look like this:

`RewriteRule ^de/rss(.*) index.php?type=9000001&L=1`

But this does not work. If i delete `de/` it works with the corresponding url.

I tried to look for similar questions here on stackoverflow, but that didn´t help.

Comment: "this does not work" - what URL does it try to go to?

Comment: Do you have `RewriteBase` specified?

Comment: after this rule is the default typo3 rewrite which sends the request to index.php which gives a 404 error. No there is no `RewriteBase` defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^de/rss/?$ index.php?type=9000001&L=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And if doesn't work then please post your full .htaccess in your question.

Comment: This works, and adarshr´s first suggestion worked too. There was another redirect from the PHP script that i havent noticed. I thought the error was in the .htacces but ist wasn´t. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/de/rss.*$    /index.php?type=9000001&L=1
```

Comment: I was missing the `/`. Please try now.

Comment: No, this doesnt fix it. Like i sait `^rss(.*)` works, `^de_rss(.*)`  works also but as soon as there ist the `/` it doesnt! I dont think i need to escape it, but maybe i am missing a needed modifier in order so work for subdirs?